# MongoDB Compass can't connect to db because Password contains unescaped characters

Tags: mongodb, escaping, mongodb-compass

I have mongo db credentials that have a [ in it. I am getting an error that says "Password contains unescaped characters". I don't know how to rectify while keeping the password the change. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me today.
Just replace the unescaped characters with the escaped code. It works.
https://docs.microfocus.com/OMi/10.62/Content/OMi/ExtGuide/ExtApps/URL_encoding.htm